# pandas drop consecutive duplicates selectively

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-manipulation

I have been looking at all questions/answers about to how drop consecutive duplicates selectively in a pandas dataframe, still cannot figure out the following scenario:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def random_dates(start, end, n, freq, seed=None):
    if seed is not None:
        np.random.seed(seed)

    dr = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
    return pd.to_datetime(np.sort(np.random.choice(dr, n, replace=False)))

date = random_dates('2018-01-01', '2018-01-12', 20, 'H', seed=[3, 1415])

data = {'Timestamp': date, 
        'Message': ['Message received.','Sending...', 'Sending...', 'Sending...', 'Work in progress...', 'Work in progress...', 
                    'Message received.','Sending...', 'Sending...','Work in progress...',
                    'Message received.','Sending...', 'Sending...', 'Sending...','Work in progress...', 'Work in progress...', 'Work in progress...',
                    'Message received.','Sending...', 'Sending...']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Timestamp', 'Message'])
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
             Timestamp              Message
0  2018-01-02 03:00:00    Message received.
1  2018-01-02 11:00:00           Sending...
2  2018-01-03 04:00:00           Sending...
3  2018-01-04 11:00:00           Sending...
4  2018-01-04 16:00:00  Work in progress...
5  2018-01-04 17:00:00  Work in progress...
6  2018-01-05 05:00:00    Message received.
7  2018-01-05 11:00:00           Sending...
8  2018-01-05 17:00:00           Sending...
9  2018-01-06 02:00:00  Work in progress...
10 2018-01-06 14:00:00    Message received.
11 2018-01-07 07:00:00           Sending...
12 2018-01-07 20:00:00           Sending...
13 2018-01-08 01:00:00           Sending...
14 2018-01-08 02:00:00  Work in progress...
15 2018-01-08 15:00:00  Work in progress...
16 2018-01-09 00:00:00  Work in progress...
17 2018-01-10 03:00:00    Message received.
18 2018-01-10 09:00:00           Sending...
19 2018-01-10 14:00:00           Sending...
```

I want to drop the consecutive duplicates in df['Message'] column ONLY when 'Message' is 'Work in progress...' and keep the first instance (here e.g. Index 5, 15 and 16 need to be dropped), ideally I would like to get:

```
             Timestamp              Message
0  2018-01-02 03:00:00    Message received.
1  2018-01-02 11:00:00           Sending...
2  2018-01-03 04:00:00           Sending...
3  2018-01-04 11:00:00           Sending...
4  2018-01-04 16:00:00  Work in progress...
6  2018-01-05 05:00:00    Message received.
7  2018-01-05 11:00:00           Sending...
8  2018-01-05 17:00:00           Sending...
9  2018-01-06 02:00:00  Work in progress...
10 2018-01-06 14:00:00    Message received.
11 2018-01-07 07:00:00           Sending...
12 2018-01-07 20:00:00           Sending...
13 2018-01-08 01:00:00           Sending...
14 2018-01-08 02:00:00  Work in progress...
17 2018-01-10 03:00:00    Message received.
18 2018-01-10 09:00:00           Sending...
19 2018-01-10 14:00:00           Sending...
```

I have tried solutions offered in similar posts like:

```
df['Message'].loc[df['Message'].shift(-1) != df['Message']]
```

I also calculated the length of the Messages:

```
df['length'] = df['Message'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

and wrote a conditional drop as:

```
df.loc[(df['length'] ==17) | (df['length'] ==10) | ~df['Message'].duplicated(keep='first')]
```

It looks better but still Index 14, 15, and 16 are dropped altogether, thus it is ill-behaved, see:

```
             Timestamp              Message  length
0  2018-01-02 03:00:00    Message received.      17
1  2018-01-02 11:00:00           Sending...      10
2  2018-01-03 04:00:00           Sending...      10
3  2018-01-04 11:00:00           Sending...      10
4  2018-01-04 16:00:00  Work in progress...      19
6  2018-01-05 05:00:00    Message received.      17
7  2018-01-05 11:00:00           Sending...      10
8  2018-01-05 17:00:00           Sending...      10
10 2018-01-06 14:00:00    Message received.      17
11 2018-01-07 07:00:00           Sending...      10
12 2018-01-07 20:00:00           Sending...      10
13 2018-01-08 01:00:00           Sending...      10
17 2018-01-10 03:00:00    Message received.      17
18 2018-01-10 09:00:00           Sending...      10
19 2018-01-10 14:00:00           Sending...      10
```

Your time and help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter first consecutive values with compare by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and chain mask with filter all rows with no `Work in progress...` values:

```
df = df[(df['Message'].shift() != df['Message']) | (df['Message'] != 'Work in progress...')]
print (df)
             Timestamp              Message
0  2018-01-02 03:00:00    Message received.
1  2018-01-02 11:00:00           Sending...
2  2018-01-03 04:00:00           Sending...
3  2018-01-04 11:00:00           Sending...
4  2018-01-04 16:00:00  Work in progress...
6  2018-01-05 05:00:00    Message received.
7  2018-01-05 11:00:00           Sending...
8  2018-01-05 17:00:00           Sending...
9  2018-01-06 02:00:00  Work in progress...
10 2018-01-06 14:00:00    Message received.
11 2018-01-07 07:00:00           Sending...
12 2018-01-07 20:00:00           Sending...
13 2018-01-08 01:00:00           Sending...
14 2018-01-08 02:00:00  Work in progress...
17 2018-01-10 03:00:00    Message received.
18 2018-01-10 09:00:00           Sending...
19 2018-01-10 14:00:00           Sending...
```

Comment: I was super close, didn't pay attention that I can add second argument in the shift clause! Wonderful. System tells me gotta wait another 6 min to accept this, it is accepted from my side, Good day.

Answer (score 2):

You can first get all Messages with 'Work in Progress' and compare them with the previous element and then filter:

```
condition = (df['Message'] == 'Work in progress...') & (df['Message']==df['Message'].shift(1))

df[~condition]

     Timestamp           Message
0   2018-01-02 03:00:00 Message received.
1   2018-01-02 11:00:00 Sending...
2   2018-01-03 04:00:00 Sending...
3   2018-01-04 11:00:00 Sending...
4   2018-01-04 16:00:00 Work in progress...
6   2018-01-05 05:00:00 Message received.
7   2018-01-05 11:00:00 Sending...
8   2018-01-05 17:00:00 Sending...
9   2018-01-06 02:00:00 Work in progress...
10  2018-01-06 14:00:00 Message received.
11  2018-01-07 07:00:00 Sending...
12  2018-01-07 20:00:00 Sending...
13  2018-01-08 01:00:00 Sending...
14  2018-01-08 02:00:00 Work in progress...
17  2018-01-10 03:00:00 Message received.
18  2018-01-10 09:00:00 Sending...
19  2018-01-10 14:00:00 Sending...
```